# How do I correctly iterate over a map to act on data from each result? I have tried several things but seem to only get one result

Tags: apex, class

I am having a problem iterating over a map and pulling values back for all associated records.  I am trying to update a text area in a work order object with the warranty status of each part in the child work detail.  I have tried a few things, but get the same result.  It is probably something really simple and I have just been looking at it too long too see it....

How do I iterate correctly through a map?  I have tried a few things but only seem to get one result.

Here is my class code:

```
    // query for the work details from the work order
    Map<Id, SVMXC__Service_Order_Line__c> workDetailsMap = new Map<Id, SVMXC__Service_Order_Line__c>();
        // query for the data and build the map using Product as the key
        for (SVMXC__Service_Order_Line__c wd : [SELECT Id
                                                                        , Name
                                                                        , SVMXC__Product__c
                                                                        , BSP_Part_Warranty_Code__c
                                                                        , SVMXC__Service_Order__c
                                                                        , SVMXC__Line_Type__c
                                                                        , BSP_Covered_Under_Product_Warranty__c
                                                                    FROM SVMXC__Service_Order_Line__c
                                                                    WHERE SVMXC__Service_Order__c IN :workDetailsToQuery
                                                                    AND SVMXC__Line_Type__c = :'Parts']) {
                                                            // add the entry to the workDetailMap and use the Product field as the key
                                                            workDetailsMap.put(wd.SVMXC__Service_Order__c, wd);
                                                            productsToQuery.add(wd.SVMXC__Product__c);
        }
```

Then I try to pull results back -

```
    for (SVMXC__Service_Order__c workOrder : triggerNew) {
        Integer i = 0;
        String p = ' ';
        String s = ' ';
        workOrder.BSP_Parts_Warranty_Status__c = ' ';        
        SVMXC__Warranty__c warranty = warrantiesMap.get(workOrder.SVMXC__Component__c); 
        //SVMXC__Service_Order_Line__c part = workDetailsMap.get(workOrder.Id) ; 

        for (Id key : workDetailsMap.keySet()) {
            SVMXC__Service_Order_Line__c parts = workDetailsMap.get(key);      
            if (parts != null){
                if (warranty != null) {
                    if (parts.BSP_Covered_Under_Product_Warranty__c != null) {                                     
                        workOrder.BSP_Claim_Warranty__c = warranty.Id;    
                        if (parts.BSP_Part_Warranty_Code__c == 'P') {
                            p = p + ' Compressor-';
                            s = S + parts.BSP_Covered_Under_Product_Warranty__c;
                        }
                        if (parts.BSP_Part_Warranty_Code__c == 'W') {
                            p = p + ' Part-';
                            s = s + parts.BSP_Covered_Under_Product_Warranty__c;
                        }
                        if (parts.BSP_Part_Warranty_Code__c == 'B') {
                            p = p + ' Board-';
                            s = s + parts.BSP_Covered_Under_Product_Warranty__c;                            
                        }
                        workOrder.BSP_Parts_Warranty_Status__c = workOrder.BSP_Parts_Warranty_Status__c + p + s + '  ' ;        
                    }
                }
                else {
                    workOrder.BSP_Parts_Warranty_Status__c = 'No Warranty';
                }
            }                                                       
            else {
                workOrder.BSP_Parts_Warranty_Status__c = 'No Parts Attached';
                workOrder.BSP_Claim_Warranty__c = null;
            }  
        }
  }
```

The warranty is always set on the work order for the last work detail record in the list.  Clearly, I am missing something...Ideas?

Comment: what is the size you are getting for workDetailsMap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using a parentID as the key to store child records, each time a child records is put into the map it overwrites the previous entry because the KEY is the same. What you want to do is this:

```
Map<Id, SVMXC__Service_Order_Line__c[]> yourmap

for(Obj var : query){

   SVMXC__Service_Order_Line__c[] tmp = yourmap.get(wd.SVMXC__Service_Order__c);

   if(tmp != null)
      tmp.add(wd);
   else
      tmp = New SVMXC__Service_Order_Line__c[]{wd};

   yourmap.put(wd.SVMXC__Service_Order__c,tmp);

}
```

Then to when you get the values you will need to:

```
SVMXC__Service_Order_Line__c parts[] = workDetailsMap.get(key);
```

and iterate over them.

Comment: Thanks Eric, I am now getting an error:  Illegal assignment from SVMXC__Service_Order_Line__c to List<SVMXC__Service_Order_Line__c>.  Looks like this line is the culprit:  SVMXC__Service_Order_Line__c[] WDList = workDetailsMap.get(wd.SVMXC__Service_Order__c);

Comment: I removed the "[]" and now I get:  "Method does not exist or incorrect signature."

Comment: @TroySmith - You will have to adjust the rest of your code to deal with a list. You initial problem was that it only had the last line item. So I assumed you wanted all the line items. You will have to iterate through the list once you get it FROM the map in the second code snippet you have

Comment: Yes, but the error is coming from the first snippet you provided (third line).  I had replaced the variable names, but it posts the same error if I use the ones you provided.  I have adjusted the code further down the line to pull it, but it isn't getting that far.

Comment: @TroySmith - did you change you map *workDetailsMap* to be: `Map<Id, SVMXC__Service_Order_Line__c[]>` - It sounds like you didn't

Comment: Ah, yes I forgot to add [ ] to a line (or two).  Thanks for your help!  So question, do I then need to set the iteration to i (like this -  [ i ]) with i being the number of work detail records?

Comment: @TroySmith - In general yes. If the answer solves the problem posted in your question please mark it as accepted so others with similar issue can find an answer and so it does not keep surfacing as unanswered. If you have additional question that are not the same as the original question please start a new question